# Post запрос не отправляется больше 2 раз

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, уже всю голову сломал, первые два запроса POST отправляются нормально, а потом вообще не меняются. JSON отправляется нормально

php

```
$array = array("1","2","3","4");

shuffle($array);

$test = array(
        "num1"=>$array[0],
        "num2"=>$array[1],
        "num3"=>$array[2],
        "num4"=>$array[3],
        "name1"=>$array[0],
        "name2"=>$array[1],
        "name3"=>$array[2],
        "name4"=>$array[3], 
        "error" => $_POST['id']
        );          
echo json_encode($test);
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){                       
  $('#my').on('click', '.clet', function() {
      var num = $(this).data('num');
      ajaxRequest(num);   
  })
});
      ajaxRequest(0);
function ajaxRequest(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id : id},
    url: 'index.php',

    success: function(jsondata){
        $('.button1').html(jsondata.name1);
        $('.button2').html(jsondata.name2);
        $('.button3').html(jsondata.name3);
        $('.button4').html(jsondata.name4);
        $('.button1').attr('data-num', jsondata.num1); 
        $('.button2').attr('data-num', jsondata.num2); 
        $('.button3').attr('data-num', jsondata.num3); 
        $('.button4').attr('data-num', jsondata.num4); 
        $('#results').html(jsondata.error);
    }
});    
}
```

html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="my">
    <a href="#" name="button1" class="button1 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button2" class="button2 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button3" class="button3 clet">кнопка</a>
    <a href="#" name="button4" class="button4 clet">кнопка</a>
</div>
<span id="results"></span>
```

Если сделать так, то все отлично работает

```
$test = array(
        "num1"=>1,
        "num2"=>2,
        "num3"=>3,
        "num4"=>4,
        "name1"=>1,
        "name2"=>2,
        "name3"=>3,
        "name4"=>4, 
        "error" => $_POST['id']

        );
echo json_encode($test);
```

Comment: Не меняется отправляемый `id`? При первой отправке он `undefined`, при второй - установленное `jsondata.num` значение, а при третьей - снова установленное в первый раз `jsondata.num`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как [было сказано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery) на английском SO:

> The first time that you use .data() to access a data-* attribute, the
>   value of that attribute is cached internally by jQuery, and .data()
>   uses the cache from then on. Updating the attribute with .attr() does
>   not update the cache, you need to use .data() to update it. That's why
>   you need to use

Что в переводе:
Когда вы используете `data()` в первый раз для доступа к атрибуту, значение кэшируется внутри *jQuery*, и потом `data()` использует данные из этого кэша.
Обновление атрибута с помощью `attr()` не обновляет кэш. Вам надо использовать `data()`, чтобы его обновить.

Следовательно, вам в запросе надо использовать не `attr`, а `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {id : id},
    url: 'index.php',

    success: function(jsondata){
        $('.button1').html(jsondata.name1);
        $('.button2').html(jsondata.name2);
        $('.button3').html(jsondata.name3);
        $('.button4').html(jsondata.name4);
        $('.button1').data('num', jsondata.num1); 
        $('.button2').data('num', jsondata.num2); 
        $('.button3').data('num', jsondata.num3); 
        $('.button4').data('num', jsondata.num4); 
        $('#results').html(jsondata.error);
    }
});
```

Comment: То, что с `.data()` у автора ошибка, - это понятно. Но вот только ли с этим - неизвестно, так как вопрос нормально не сформулирован. Я, собственно, поэтому ответ про `.data()` размещать и не стал.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание вопроса, все получилось и спасибо за помощь